# AGIC connectivity between pod and app gateway

Tags: nginx-ingress, azure-aks

Having issue in the connectivity between app gateway backendpool with aks pod ip. The Pod that I deployed websocket-deployment(10.240.0.17) is on the different subnet as the actual Nodes (aks-agentpool-13682822-vmss000000 --> 10.60.x.4). When I try to add the pod IP as backendpool in application gateway waf v2 ( which is in the same vnet as aks) its not working. The backend pool is not healthy. I guess it’s unable to connect pod with IP (10.240.0.17). Any help is much appreciated. The issue is only when I use AGIC with vmss.

Comment: what monitor have you configured for your appGW backendpool ? please share

Comment: which AKS networking are you using ? Azure (CNI) or Kubenet ? We use Azure CNI which makes the POD's IP on the same as the NODE IP (in the same subnet range) this would allow your POD IP to be used as a backend

Answer (score 1):

To allow your service to be added to the AppGW as a backendpool member, it will need to be reachable by the AppGW. Since the 10.240.X.X CIDR isn't reachable and its internal to the AKS Cluster, you will need to expose your pod using a Service of type Load Balancer on the private VNET.

Following this DOC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb you will be able to create a service for your PODs which will expose your pod over an internal IP on the VNEt/Subnet 10.60.X.X. this IP range will be available to your AppGw is you are using a subnet for AKS that is in the same VNET as your AppGW subnet.

If they are in a different VNET, you should be able to do a VNET peering to connect the two VNET together.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview

Comment: Thanks for the information. I’m able to setup the AGIC setup in the cluster. The only issue now is that the application gateway unable to connect to the cluster using the vmss as backendpool. If I’m using AGIC without VMSS, it works fine. Since the backendpool is pointing to VMSS instead of Pod Ip, the backend health is failing with error unable to connect to the server. All the required NSG’s are in place to communicate between the subnets. App gateway and Aks both are in the same VNET. Can you please help on this issue.

Comment: How do you expect to route to an app when connecting the AppGW to a VMSS ?

Comment: We are using different subnet for node as it’s a standard template we follow for any aks deployment. Since we are using VMSS, the POD cidr 10.244.x.x/24 is taken by default during provision. The issue is now that after AGIC deployment the Pod ips are fall under 10.244.x.x range and the node ips are 10.60.x.x range. VNET peering between app gateway and pod cidr won’t work as the pod cidr range is within aks. But Aks and app gateway are within the same vnet.

Comment: How will I expose my app over vmss as the pod ip is not reachable from app gateway. Really need help in this regard as we are stuck and can’t proceed further.

Comment: You should use Azure CNI instead of Kubenet.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-azure-cni

Comment: this will allow your POD CIDR to be on the same block as your NODE CIDR, hence having more control and allowing your App GW to connect to the NODE/POD CIDR over peering.

Comment: Yeah that configuration worked in QA. But we do have our standards to follow the subnet for AKS and App gateway to use the VNET and subnets. Since I used VMSS for auto scaling, the pod CIDR took automatically. I can’t change the configuration now. Is there any other possible options to make it work other than exposing the services to load balancer.

Comment: Is there any possibility to connect via VMSS. There should be an option to enable communication from app gateway to services via vmss.

Comment: What you need to do is to have your Service IP range on the subnet range by using an Internal Load Balancer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb this will allow your POD to be on the private CIR zone while exposing your service over the private Subnet using the Advanced networking with AKS to use your own Subnet. The Azure Internal LB will have a reachable IP for your AppGW to use.

Comment: I prefer going for nginx ingress controller instead AGIC or just go for exposing the service to internal LB. using the both options, I can make my app up and running. But, the reason behind going for AGIC doesn't serve the purpose, if I use the internal LB.